# My timer freezes everytime I leave the scene and come back.

Tags: scripting, unity-game-engine, unityscript, countdowntimer

My timer code:

```
#pragma strict
private var initialtime : float;
private var texttime : String;
var CountMinutes : int;
var CountSeconds : int;
private var restseconds : int;
private var minutes : int;
private var seconds : int;
var guitime : float;

function Start () {
    initialtime=Time.time;
    CountSeconds = CountSeconds + (CountMinutes*60);
}

function OnGUI () {
    guitime = Time.time - initialtime;
    restseconds = CountSeconds -     guitime;
    seconds = restseconds%60;
    minutes = restseconds/60;
    texttime = String.Format("{0}:{1}",minutes, seconds);
    GetComponent(GUIText).text = texttime;

        if(seconds <=0 && minutes <=0)
        {
        //Pause the game
        Time.timeScale = 0;         
     DontDestroyOnLoad(GameObject.Find("Diamond"));
                 Application.LoadLevel("Score");
    }
```

I have this script on another object that loads a new scene then in that scene there is a button that lets me go back to the timer scene again then when I am in the timer scene the timer just doesn't move. I don't get why. But theres this other button that loads another scene and if I return to the timer scene the timer would work fine. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're changing scenes constantly (like you're doing when showing the score), you should change the Start() function with the Awake() function.

If I recall correctly, the Start function runs once in the whole time, whereas Awake runs every time the script is loaded.

Besides that, are you reverting Time.timeScale back? Maybe you're leaving at 0.

And as a last option, maybe you should do these whole script in Update() instad OnGui():

> if(seconds <=0 && minutes <=0)
>          {
>
> ```
>    //Pause the game
>    Time.timeScale = 0;         
>    DontDestroyOnLoad(GameObject.Find("Diamond"));
>    Application.LoadLevel("Score");
> ```

Comment: How can I fix this problem then